# Trace a ccsprite cocos2d-iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a layer with a sprite of a simple black donut. I want the user to be able to draw on the sprite in a different color (which I've managed to do without any problem using CCRenderTexture).

My question is how I can calculate whether the image has been traced at least 95% (meaning, find out when 95% of the black pixels are now the new color). I've tried methods like taking a screenshot of the layer and counting the number of black pixels, but it hasn't worked that well (using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262893/1577738).

It would be even better if I could just change the color of each pixel as it's touched (to avoid issues with coloring out of the lines). I could theoretically just split the donut into like 10 sprites and change that section's color if the user touches it, but that seems ridiculous if I give the user options to use a bunch of different colors.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Your suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading pixel colors will be rather inaccurate and slow. I suggest dividing the area into smaller rectangles (ie 8x8 or 4x4) and then flag each as "visited" when the user draws on it. If most rectangle areas are flagged, the user has drawn on most parts of the texture.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Thanks for your help! I've used your site a bunch.